# Не передается response в функцию (JSON, Retrofit, JAVA)

Tags: java, json, retrofit

Получаю response:

```
private void getresponse() throws IOException {
        Retrofit retrofit = NetworkClient.getRetrofitClient();
        WallInterface wallInterface = retrofit.create(WallInterface.class);
        Call<String> call = wallInterface.getresponse("-116125443", "0", "5", "5.52", "token");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    if (response.body() !=null){
                        System.out.println("onSuccess - " +response.body().toString());
                        String jsonresponse = response.body().toString();
                        System.out.println("onSuccessJsonResponse - " + jsonresponse);
                        //textView.setText(jsonresponse);
                        writeResponse(jsonresponse);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("not Success");
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

В консоль значение выводится. А как только пишу функцию для передачи текстовых значений в поле TextView по клику кнопки - информация не передается. Вот функция:

```
private void writeResponse(String response){
        try
        {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
            ArrayList<Item> itemArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            JSONArray dataArray = obj.getJSONArray("items");

            for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++){
                Item item = new Item();

            JSONObject dataodj = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);
                item.setText(dataodj.getString("text"));

                itemArrayList.add(item);

        }
            for (int j=0; j < itemArrayList.size(); j++){
                textView.setText(itemArrayList.get(j).getText() + "\n");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void OnClick(View view) throws IOException {
        getresponse();

    }
}
```

тело response:

```
{"response":{"count":30,"items":[{"id":31,"from_id":-116125443,"owner_id":-116125443,"date":1503404720,"marked_as_ads":0,"post_type":"post","text":"Еще одно подтверждение, как здорово заходят хиты даже через 15 лет. Немцы Reamonn в начале 2000-х сделали прорыв со своей меланхоличной \"Supergirl\". В 2017 году их успеть решили повторить Anna Nackab.","signer_id":276417933,"can_delete":1,"can_pin":1,"attachments":[{"type":"audio","audio":{"artist":"Программа \"Сэмпл один на Всех!\"","id":456241280,"owner_id":2000147926,"title":"Reamon vs. Anna Naclab","duration":25,"url":"https:\/\/vk.com\/mp3\/audio_api_unavailable.mp3","date":1503404721,"genre_id":1001}}],"post_source":{"type":"vk"},"comments":{"count":2,"can_post":1},"likes":{"count":5,"user_likes":1,"can_like":0,"can_publish":1},"reposts":{"count":1,"user_reposted":1}},{"id":30,"from_id":-116125443,"owner_id":-116125443,"date":1480571513,"marked_as_ads":0,"post_type":"post","text":"В 1991 году песня Марка Коэна \"Walking in Memphis\" появилась в эфирах радиостанций. За все время своего существования песня \"обросла\" каверами и ремиксами, использовалась в качестве саундтреков к фильмам. И по сей день припев песни является самым узнаваемым! Кстати, и по сей день это один из успешных синглов США и Великобритании.","can_delete":1,"can_pin":1,"attachments":[{"type":"audio","audio":{"artist":"Программа \"Сэмпл один на Всех!\"","id":456240538,"owner_id":2000129726,"title":"DJ Smash vs. Marc Cohn","duration":25,"url":"https:\/\/vk.com\/mp3\/audio_api_unavailable.mp3","date":1480571513,"genre_id":18}}],"post_source":{"type":"vk"},"comments":{"count":0,"can_post":1},"likes":{"count":5,"user_likes":1,"can_like":0,"can_publish":1},"reposts":{"count":1,"user_reposted":1}},{"id":29,"from_id":-116125443,"owner_id":-116125443,"date":1480338116,"marked_as_ads":0,"post_type":"post","text":"В 2000-х хит от группы \"Руки Вверх\" \"Песенка №5\" зазвучала на европейских танцполах в англоязычном варианте. Вот это, действительно оказалось приятным. Русскоязычная песня стала основой для многих кавер-версий и ремиксов от Атлантики до Тихого океана! Как это произошло - в нашей программе!","can_delete":1,"can_pin":1,"attachments":[{"type":"audio","audio":{"artist":"Программа \"Сэмпл один на Всех!\"","id":456240399,"owner_id":2000124826,"title":"Руки Вверх vs. ATC","duration":25,"url":"","date":1480338116,"genre_id":18,"no_search":1,"content_restricted":1}}],"post_source":{"type":"vk"},"comments":{"count":0,"can_post":1},"likes":{"count":7,"user_likes":1,"can_like":0,"can_publish":1},"reposts":{"count":1,"user_reposted":1}},{"id":28,"from_id":-116125443,"owner_id":-116125443,"date":1480337719,"marked_as_ads":0,"post_type":"post","text":"Музыка преображает человека. Напевая любимый мотив, Вы преображаете все вокруг. А припев современной песни так и просится запомнится... А если мотив песни Вы можете вспомнить через несколько лет, то главная задача автора решена - Вы стали его поклонником . Как изменялась одна популярная песня на протяжении нескольких лет. Добро пожаловать в мир программы.","can_delete":1,"can_pin":1,"attachments":[{"type":"audio","audio":{"artist":"Программа \"Сэмпл один на Всех!\"","id":456240300,"owner_id":2000124943,"title":"Frida Gold vs. Gala","duration":25,"url":"https:\/\/vk.com\/mp3\/audio_api_unavailable.mp3","date":1480337719,"genre_id":18}}],"post_source":{"type":"vk"},"comments":{"count":0,"can_post":1},"likes":{"count":4,"user_likes":1,"can_like":0,"can_publish":1},"reposts":{"count":1,"user_reposted":1}},{"id":27,"from_id":-116125443,"owner_id":-116125443,"date":1467535791,"marked_as_ads":0,"post_type":"post","text":"Этой истории уже более 10-ти лет. Для современной музыкальной истории не такой большой срок, но тем не менее, изменения очевидны.  DJ David Guetta еще раз подтвердил свое умение делать хорошие хиты, пусть и на старом материале. Об этом в нашей программе.","can_delete":1,"can_pin":1,"attachments":[{"type":"audio","audio":{"artist":"Программа \"Сэмпл Один на Всех!\"","id":456239491,"owner_id":2000338373,"title":"David Guetta vs. Alice Deejay","duration":25,"url":"https:\/\/vk.com\/mp3\/audio_api_unavailable.mp3","date":1467535791,"genre_id":18}}],"post_source":{"type":"vk"},"comments":{"count":0,"can_post":1},"likes":{"count":6,"user_likes":1,"can_like":0,"can_publish":1},"reposts":{"count":1,"user_reposted":1}}]}}
```

Что не так?

Comment: Дебагом не пробовали пройти?

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то `onResponse` не на основном потоке срабатывает и трогать `View` в нём нельзя. Т.е. надо запускать `textView.setText(itemArrayList.get(j).getText() + "\n");` явно в `UI`-потоке. Попробуйте так: `textView.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        textView.setText(itemArrayList.get(j).getText() + "\n");
    }
});`. Правда, если это предположение верно, то у вас приложение должно падать, чего, наверное, у вас не происходит...  Также вы так не добавите весь текст, т.к. перезаписываете его в каждой итерации цикла. Используйте `append()` метод вместо `setText()`

Comment: Ну и у вас в коде можно сделать 2 радикальных улучшения: 1. Объявить в Retrofit возвращаемым значением метода сразу же класс, описывающий JSON, чтобы либа самостоятельно JSON распарсила в указанную модель. 2. Использовать RxJava - так у вас код будет лаконичнее и не будет проблемы с потоками - в 2 строчки можно определить на каком потоке делать запрос и в какой поток передавать ответ.

Comment: Возможно, также, проблема в том, что вам надо строку `String jsonresponse = response.body().toString();` перенести на 1 строку выше. Вроде как вызвать успешно `response.body().toString();` можно только один раз.

Comment: Спасибо. RxJava не щупал, мне сложно сказать. А остальные вещи проверю. Думал вообще по-другому написать. Но взял для себя стандартный пример по Retrofit и запилил под себя. Дебагом, кстати, не проходил...

Comment: Проблема в том, что в функцию write Response не передаётся jsonresponse. В getresponse все великолепно. Попробую все в одном сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Переделал функцию:

```
private void writeResponse(String response){
        try
        {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
            ArrayList<Item> itemArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            JSONArray dataArray = obj.getJSONArray("items");

            for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++){
                Item item = new Item();

            JSONObject dataodj = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);
                item.setText(dataodj.getString("text"));

                itemArrayList.add(item);

        }
            for (int j=0; j < itemArrayList.size(); j++){
                textView.append(itemArrayList.get(j).getText() + "\n");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```